# Row cols aren't aligning - image is going into a completely new row

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

Trying to work on making the header portion of my website (starting with the mobile class). When I am trying to create a col-xs-7 which contains one h1 and two p tags, and a col-xs-5 which contains an image. The col-xs-7 completely takes over the entire row and throws the col-xs-5 column into a new row. Spent some time reading documentation and similar questions, but still got the same results. Below is a diagram of the results I'm getting and a code snippet. Cheers!

[image: Example]

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <h1 class="text-justify">Name</h1>
            <p class="text-justify">Company</p>
            <p class="text-justify">Role</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <img class="img-fluid w-25 float-end" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the class `float-end` class on the image which moves the element out of flow and floats it. Also note, that Bootstrap 5+ has no `xs` breakpoint as it is the default breakpoint.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7">
            <h1 class="text-justify">Name</h1>
            <p class="text-justify">Company</p>
            <p class="text-justify">Role</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification. This was exactly what I was hoping to get out of it

Answer (score 0):

I think using flexBox will give you more control

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="d-flex flex-nowrap">
  <div class="p-2">
    <h1 class="text-justify">Name</h1>
    <p class="text-justify">Company</p>
    <p class="text-justify">Role</p>
  </div>
  <div class="p-2">
    <img class="img-fluid w-25 float-end" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Documentation on flex and the wrap properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/)

(I'm not familiar with bootstrap so my example will need some tweaking. This would be my approach using vanilla css.)

Comment: Yours and the other comment went well hand in hand. Thanks for that - I'll probably keep evaluating the site as it progresses and keep this in mind

Comment: @CHues please note for the feature: `here` is a poor description for a link because it is not accessible. The description of the link should always contain a description of the content. Then link the correct version of the documentation. The OP specifically stated to use Bootstrap-5. It is in most cases not helpful to link to a different version (4.0 not even 4.6). There are many changes between 4 and 5 that in other cases would have been crucial.